Usage of add_constructor() in 0.18.x
One of my packages (tinject), currently using ruamel.yaml 0.17.x, installs a custom constructor to implement a !include directive allowing me to write a document like:
foo:
  - bar: 42

---

bar:
  - foo: 42
  - text: !include 'test.txt'


When I run the following simplified script:
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint

from ruamel import yaml


def include(loader, node):
    path = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    fullpath = include.basedir / path
    return fullpath.read_text('utf-8')


yaml.add_constructor('!include', include, Loader=yaml.Loader)


def load(fname):
    include.basedir = fname.parent
    with fname.open() as stream:
        content = yaml.load_all(stream, Loader=yaml.Loader)
        pprint(list(content))


print("ruamel.yaml.__version__ ==", yaml.__version__)
load(Path('/tmp/ruamel-test/test.yml'))

with a test.txt file containing
This
is
the
text

I obtain the following output:
ruamel.yaml.__version__ == 0.17.32
[{'foo': [{'bar': 42}]},
 {'bar': [{'foo': 42}, {'text': 'This\nis\nthe\ntext\n'}]}]

Now I have the need to upgrade it to 0.18.x, where the top level load_all() functions have been dropped, and indeed running under that version I get the following instead:
ruamel.yaml.__version__ == 0.18.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ruamel-test/test.py", line 24, in <module>
    load(Path('/tmp//ruamel-test/test.yml'))
  File "/tmp/ruamel-test/test.py", line 19, in load
    content = yaml.load_all(stream, Loader=yaml.Loader)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/nix/store/8zvc8cgw8bpi1i3c0zpd4xhjcg6f9shr-python3-3.11.9-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 1096, in load_all
    error_deprecation('load_all', 'load_all', arg=_error_dep_arg, comment=_error_dep_comment)
  File "/nix/store/8zvc8cgw8bpi1i3c0zpd4xhjcg6f9shr-python3-3.11.9-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/main.py", line 1039, in error_deprecation
    raise AttributeError(s, name=None)
AttributeError: 
"load_all()" has been removed, use

  yaml = YAML(typ='rt')
  yaml.load_all(...)

and register any classes that you use, or check the tag attribute on the loaded data,
instead of file "/tmp/ruamel-test/test.py", line 19

        content = yaml.load_all(stream, Loader=yaml.Loader)

After several attempts, I eventually found a solution that apparently gives me the expected result, and I'm asking if what I'm doing is the right thing or if instead I'm missing some (even) simpler way.
At first, I modified my script like the following:
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint

from ruamel import yaml


def include(loader, node):
    path = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    fullpath = include.basedir / path
    return fullpath.read_text('utf-8')


yaml.add_constructor('!include', include)


def load(fname):
    include.basedir = fname.parent
    with fname.open() as stream:
        content = yaml.YAML().load_all(stream)
        pprint(list(content))


print("ruamel.yaml.__version__ ==", yaml.__version__)
load(Path('/tmp//ruamel-test/test.yml'))

and this emits this:
ruamel.yaml.__version__ == 0.18.6
[{'foo': [{'bar': 42}]},
 {'bar': [{'foo': 42}, {'text': TaggedScalar(value='test.txt', style="'", tag=Tag('!include'))}]}]

where the include() constructor is never called.

What eventually worked is something like this:
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint

from ruamel import yaml


class MyConstructor(yaml.Constructor):
    pass


def include(loader, node):
    path = loader.construct_scalar(node)
    fullpath = include.basedir / path
    return fullpath.read_text('utf-8')


MyConstructor.add_constructor('!include', include)


def load(fname):
    include.basedir = fname.parent
    with fname.open() as stream:
        y = yaml.YAML()
        y.Constructor = MyConstructor
        content = y.load_all(stream)
        pprint(list(content))


print("ruamel.yaml.__version__ ==", yaml.__version__)
load(Path('/tmp//ruamel-test/test.yml'))

that produces:
ruamel.yaml.__version__ == 0.18.6
[{'foo': [{'bar': 42}]},
 {'bar': [{'foo': 42}, {'text': 'This\nis\nthe\ntext\n'}]}]

Is this (that is, creating my own Constructor subclass and explicitly adding the constructor there) the recommended way now?
Thanks in advance & bye.

Yes this is the proper way to go. With the deprecated function load_all() you would use instances that where globally modified by add_constructor chaning the class variables. With the creation of the YAML() instance, I wanted to move away from these global changes, so you can have different instance doing different things (e.g. dumping to different widths, having different tags registered etc).

Thank you, maybe this deserves an example/explanation in the doc?
